# Design a function $f(x)$ such that $\lim_{x\rightarrow1^-} \frac{1-x}{1-f(x)} = 0$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

Is it possible to design a function $f(x)$ with $x \in (0,1)$ such that $\lim_{x\rightarrow1^-} \frac{1-x}{1-f(x)} = 0$? What would a general family of such functions look like? An initial attempt at analyzing the problem led to observing that since the problem deals with the value of the limit as $x$ approaches $1$ from the left, the numerator gets closer and closer to $0$. Thus, we would probably end up with an indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$ where L'Hospital's Theorem could play a role.

Also, Is it possible to design a function $f(x, S)$ where $S$ represents a set of variables such that $\lim_{x\rightarrow1^-} \frac{1-x}{1-f(x)} = 0$? Thus, $f(x, S)$ represents a function which depends both on $x$ and the set of other variables $S$. I could make a little headway into this by noting that the limit does not basically depend on $S$, thus, the problem probably reduces to the first one.

EDIT : What would be the function design if it was required the value of the function is in the open interval $(0,1)$, i.e., $f(x,S) \in (0,1)$?

Comment: Is it required that $\lim_{x \to 1^-} f(x) = 1$?  If not, take $f(x) = 0.$

Comment: @user2661923 I have added an EDIT

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm having trouble following your edit.  It seems to me that there are only two possibilities: **either** $\lim x\to 1^- f(x) = 1$ or it **doesn't**.  If it doesn't, the problem is immediately trivial.  If it does, then before anything else, I (personally) would invoke L'Hopital's rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any function such that

$$\forall x\in(0,1):f(x)\ne 1\land \lim_{x\to1^-}f(x)\ne 1.$$

There are zillions such functions !

**Update:**

This is irrelevant, due to me misunderstanding the question. (But what follows is correct.)

---

With $\lim_{x\to1^-}f(x)= 1$, take

$$f(x)\ne 1\land f(x)=1-o(x-1).$$

There are still zillions of such functions. E.g. $$f(x)=1-\sqrt{1-x}.$$

Comment: I don't think you asked the right question, as the answer is trivial.

Comment: I actually meant $f(x,S) \in (0,1)$, the open interval

Comment: @ephemeral: ooops, yes, sorry. My second part is still valid.

Comment: Do you mean the bound by $o(x-1)$? I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with the expression, maybe a little english description would held further

Comment: @ephemeral: this is a standard notation, it reads "little-o". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation

Comment: Thanks! What would be the way to formally prove that $f(x)\ne 1\land f(x)=1-o(x-1)$ indeed satisfies the limit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/114014/discussion-between-ephemeral-and-yves-daoust).

Answer (score 1):

Take $f(x)=0$ so that for $x<1$ you have
$$\frac{1-x}{1-f(x)}=\frac{1-x}{1-0}=1-x.$$
The same works for any number of variables, so you could also take $f(x,S)=0$.

---

As for the edit adding the requirement that $f(x,S)\in(0,1)$; for any constant $c\neq1$ the function $f(x,S)=c$ works, as then
$$\frac{1-x}{1-f(x,S)}=\frac{1}{1-c}(1-x).$$

Comment: Is it possible to design a function such that $f(x, S)$ remains in $(0,1)$ while the limit holds?

Comment: @ephemeral Sure; for any constant $c\neq1$ you get that $f(x,S)=c$ yields
$$\frac{1-x}{1-f(x,S)}=\frac{1}{1-c}(1-x).$$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I din't downvote, I upvoted!

Comment: Maybe this part you should put in the answer too since I have added an explicit EDIT to the question for this scenario, and perhaps an English explanation o what this expression denotes

Answer (score 1):

The reasoning is much easier by the change of variable $x=1-t$ and the change of function $1-f(x)=g(t)$. Now your question is

$$\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac t{g(t)}=0$$ and simply says that $g$ goes slower to zero than $t$. (F.i. $t^\alpha$ with $0<\alpha<1$.)

Answer (score 1):

We define what $ f(x) $ should *not* be, rather than what it should be.

Choose /design any $f(x) $ so that

$$\boxed{f(1)\ne 1} $$

so the denominator does not go to zero. For example if an unsuitable choice like

$$ f(x)=\tan\; ( \frac{\pi x}{4})$$

is made then at $x=1$ we have $\dfrac{0}{0}$ and by L'Hospital's Rule the limit is

$$ \cos^2 \frac{\pi}{4}=\frac12$$

a finite non-zero limit, that you do not want.